# adding uid to operator causes "Cannot map checkpoint/savepoint state for operator"

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I have a simple pipeline

```
env.addSource(kafkaConsumer).uid("kafka-src").name(consumerName)
    .keyBy(_.id)
    .process(new Processor).uid("processor")
    .addSink(kafkaProducer).name(producerName)
```

now I tried simply adding `uid` to the sink like this

```
env.addSource(kafkaConsumer).uid("kafka-src").name(consumerName)
    .keyBy(_.id)
    .process(new Processor).uid("processor")
    .addSink(kafkaProducer).name(producerName).uid("kafka-sink")
```

but I am getting very long exception that seems that this is the part of the message :

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to rollback to checkpoint/savepoint file:/tmp/rocksdb/savepoint-445173-011657873d74. Cannot map checkpoint/savepoint state for operator 3cfeb06db0484d5556a7de8db2025f09 to the new program, because the operator is not available in the new program. If you want to allow to skip this, you can set the --allowNonRestoredState option on the CLI.
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.checkpoint.Checkpoints.loadAndValidateCheckpoint(Checkpoints.java:205)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.checkpoint.CheckpointCoordinator.restoreSavepoint(CheckpointCoordinator.java:1103)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmaster.JobMaster.tryRestoreExecutionGraphFromSavepoint(JobMaster.java:1251)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmaster.JobMaster.createAndRestoreExecutionGraph(JobMaster.java:1175)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmaster.JobMaster.<init>(JobMaster.java:299)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmaster.factories.DefaultJobMasterServiceFactory.createJobMasterService(DefaultJobMasterServiceFactory.java:83)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmaster.factories.DefaultJobMasterServiceFactory.createJobMasterService(DefaultJobMasterServiceFactory.java:37)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmaster.JobManagerRunner.<init>(JobManagerRunner.java:146)
```

is that makes sense ? is there anyway to resolve it without loosing the savepoint ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem makes sense because if you don't specify the IDs manually they will be generated automatically. Probably the generated ID is `3cfeb06db0484d5556a7de8db2025f09`.

You have three choices:

1. Start the job without savepoint: which will result in loss of data;
2. Run the job allowing non-restored state;
3. Use `3cfeb06db0484d5556a7de8db2025f09` as `uid` of your operator.

Here are some links that may help you:

- [Assigning Operator IDs](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/ops/state/savepoints.html#assigning-operator-ids)
- [Allowing Non-Restored State](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/ops/state/savepoints.html#allowing-non-restored-state)
- [What happens if I delete an operator that has state from my job?](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/ops/state/savepoints.html#what-happens-if-i-delete-an-operator-that-has-state-from-my-job)

Comment: `Run the job allowing non-restored state` means that it will be restored without savepoint (which will result in data loss as point #1 ) ?

Comment: @igx Yes, like the first choice. How about the 3rd option? Does it solve?

Comment: The 3rd option did solve it using `setUidHash` and that value